# How to update the categories of existing custom post types?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am picking up work on a legacy tool and am redoing a page that works with custom post types. The new post type we'll call **new_resource**, and has the same "category" identifiers as the existing legacy resource type, **old_resource**. I'm pretty new to Wordpress, so there may have been a better way of doing that than just starting from scratch, but this is where I'm at. My goal is to use the same data that the existing resources used, so I don't have to create all of the new posts.

I ran two queries that updated the existing resource types to the new one:

```
update wp_posts set post_type = 'new_resource' where post_type = 'old_resource';
```

and

```
update wp_posts set guid = replace(guid, 'old-resource', 'new-resource');
```

All of that is working.

What I want to do now is update the custom taxonomy (I'm not using the default categories built in). We'll call it **resource-category** for the example. The existing old-resource posts all had their resource-category assigned, and when I query wp_terms, I can see all of the categories. I've set up those SAME categories in the new-resource type. Is there a query that I can run that will select all of the resources with a type of new-resources (all of them are now, after I ran that update query above), and set their categories? Like update their term_id where the term_id is still pointing to an ID of the old category type?

Wordpress Version: 4.2.2
PHP Version: 5.3.3

### Edit:

I ran this query:

`mysql> select term_id, name, slug from wp_terms where slug = 'videos';`

```
+---------+--------+--------+
| term_id | name   | slug   |
+---------+--------+--------+
|      69 | Videos | videos |
|     177 | Videos | videos |
+---------+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The term_id 69 belongs to the old resource type. The term_id 177 belongs to the new resource. I want all of my current resources (the ones I already ran the update resource type query on) to point to term_id 177 instead of 69, but I'm not sure of the relationship between posts and terms.

Something like update the term_id for all new-resources, set 69 to 177.

Comment: Your question is not clear  .. try post  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge is that any less confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update set only the column in set clause  .. and i set clause ypu can have more than a column

You could do the two update using an update only

```
 update wp_posts 
         set post_type = 'new_resource', 
         guid = replace(guid, 'old-resource', 'new-resource')
 where post_type = 'old_resource';
```

Comment: How does this fix the category issue though? Or was this just a comment on how I did my previous queries?

Comment: what is your problem with category  ?   .. you can assign the value you prefer  eg : just adding category_id = 4 to you set clause

Comment: I see what you're saying. I can just set the term_id for each post to the updated term_id (I added some query code above for a category of type video). I think I am just confused about the relationship between the wp_terms table and the wp_post. I assumed that the wp_posts table had a foreign key from the wp_terms table, but not sure what it would be.

Comment: I don't understand  .. try show a real sample using al the tables  involved  and show the expected  result too ..

Comment: So you didn't specifically answer me, but your questions led to me figuring out, so I will accept it. I was confused on how the Wordpress tables were linked together through keys, and so writing out those queries helped.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I ran a query that selected all of the info I'm comparing:

```
SELECT p.post_title as “wp_post_title”, tr.term_taxonomy_id as “term_rship_id”, tt.taxonomy as “term_tax_name”, tm.slug as “terms_slug”
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'exp_wp_resource_category' or tt.taxonomy = 'resource-categories';
```

Then I updated my existing taxonomy_ids in the wp_term_relationship table.

```
UPDATE wp_term_relationships SET term_taxonomy_id = 176 WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 13;
```

13 is the ID of the old-resource video type, and 175 is the ID of the new-resource video type.

Just took some digging through the Wordpress table relationships.